# Iterator() over query objects django

Tags: python, mysql, django, iteration

I need to iterate over some `query objects` from my database and display them on the template, I have model field like price, cost and profit, the idea is to not to parse directly because the list will be to large in real env, so I have started with something like this

```
from __future__ import print_function
from django.views.generic import ListView

from projects.models import Project
from .services import CurrencyConversionService


    class ProjectStatisticsList(ListView):
        model = Project
        template_name = 'statistics/statistics_list.html'

        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(ProjectStatisticsList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        for context['price_aux'] in Project.objects.all().iterator():
            # do the iteration here and later for loop in tempalte
            pass
        return context
```

models fields

```
price_aux = models.DecimalField('price aux', max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, default=0, blank=True, null=True)
cost_aux = models.DecimalField('cost aux', max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, default=0, blank=True, null=True)
profit_aux = models.DecimalField('profit aux', max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, default=0, blank=True, null=True)
```

My problem is that I don't have an idea how can I do this, can someone please help me understand how can I do this, thanks.

Comment: I rolled back your edit because it complete invalidated the original question. The edit didn't make any sense anyway - all you needed to do was annotate the queryset you were using

Comment: @Sayse ok, I will do that, one thing I forgot to mention is that I need to convert this data to one currency, so that was my concern from the start, so can I still use annotate and aggregate after I convert my data?

Answer (score 2):

There's a clear misunderstanding of what the "template" is here as well as querysets.

Django templates are still constructed server side so even if you did do this, you'd still be iterating over all the elements you want at the same point anyway so you're not saving any time.

Also, querysets are evaluated lazily so the results aren't retrieved until you need them which is probably what you hope your "iterator" would do.